# Mobs becoming invisible in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I've recently started up a CraftBukkit server in Minecraft and an issue that has recently occurred, is that mobs, passive, neutral and hostile, are now all invisible. I know for a fact that they are spawning because I summoned a Cow just to see if they simply were not spawning. What I found out was that when I executed `/summon Cow`, nothing spawned, or so I thought, after a few seconds I heard it "moo". I was baffled at first so I naturally looked around to see if there were cows in the vicinity, but nothing. I tried again but only with a spawn egg and I had the same results. So I then restart my server and tried again and STILL got the same results as before. I did some research and came to the conclusion that it could be the actual CraftBukkit download itself, but I'm skeptical, only because this has never happened before with the same CraftBukkit build.

From what I've gathered, the likely result could be that the problem is within my "worlds" folder because I've had to replace that folder before due to terrain generating issues. The mobs have always been able to be visible before in the previous folders as well. I also have check my server.properties file just to make sure that my `spawn-animals` and `spawn-mobs` are both set to `true` and still have no visible mobs, only sounds.

Comment: Probably not it, but is it possible that the textures have been corrupted/removed/aren't loading? E.g. some graphics enhancements mods do special things with mobs that may be broken (Either a mod incomparability or old versions) If you're using any graphics mods/texture packs, try disabling them and check it again.

Comment: @DBS I'm not using any mods on my server, just plugins. So the possibilities of it being a mod is out. However, you mentioning that the textures could be corrupted in some form has brought to my attention that it could very possibly be that. How would I be able to fix the textures not loading or being corrupted in general?

Comment: By the seems of it, your server isn't sending "Hey! There's a [mob name] here" when you load a new chunk with mobs in it... Or that your game does not register the new mobs when the server sends the "There's a mob here." data with the newly loaded chunk. Most likely, it's actually your game - I've experienced this before; all my friends could see mobs, whereas I can't.

Comment: @aytimothy so how could I fix that? would it involve creating another world and deleting the old one?

Comment: I'm not sure @benimen16.

Comment: Do you have an unusually high ping time between you and the server?

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you have to download both the resource and behavior pack. cause if you only download the behavior pack, the mod will be there, you just won't be able to see it because the resource pack creates the image of the mobs in the mod, and that's why you have to include it sometimes and without it, the mod won't be visible on your screen, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make a repeating command block that runs this command:

```
effect clear @e invisibilty
```

See if that works, someone might've made another command block that gives entities invisibility.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen to me and I've fixed it. I've found that it's a rendering error, and if you change your render distance, it should self-correct.

Answer (score 0):

Outdated plugins can cause this. I once had a tab plugin that ended up making mobs invisible, and the plugin was outdated.

Answer (score -1):

It could likely be possible that another person o your server is throwing potions on the mobs to make them invisible or the graphics could possibly not be loading... This could be from accidentally removing files from your sever to cause these glitches.

Comment: None of this seems likely other than the possible file removal.

Answer (score -2):

It only works in armor stands, because when I reviewed the invisible armor stand command,I realized it only works on armor stands. So don't bluff about it. But don't try to summon a Normal Mob (Such As Zombie,Spider,etc.) making it invisible but can use the ActiveEffects. Use /summon (Mob) ~ ~ ~ {ActiveEffects:[{Id:14
,Amplfier:1,Duration:999999}]} Hope this helped!